# How to calculate number of Mondays left in a month with Python

Tags: python

I'm building out a forecast model in Python and need to calculate the number of remaining days for each day name of a month. For example, on October 25, 2017 there are no remaining Wednesdays in the current month and there is 1 remaining Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday.

I'm able to achieve the same result in R with:

```
first <- as.Date(cut(Sys.Date(), "month"))
last <- as.Date(cut(first + 31, "month")) - 1
sum(format(seq(Sys.Date(), last, "day"), "%w") == 0) -> Sunday
```

I'm trying to edit the following code block which was initially intended to count weekdays in a month for my purposes but not sure if I'm on the right track

```
import calendar

weekday_count = 0
cal = calendar.Calendar()

for week in cal.monthdayscalendar(2013, 8):
for i, day in enumerate(week):
    # not this month's day or a weekend
    if day == 0 or i >= 5:
        continue
    # or some other control if desired...
    weekday_count += 1

print(weekday_count)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: `I'm able to achieve the same result in R with:` > Then why did you tag this as a Python question??

Comment: because I need to do this in Python

Comment: @kame sorry for omitting my original code - i've included what i'm working with so far, as well as an example with R (if that would be helpful in further explaining the solution I'm looking for)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this as a starting point. It will calculate the number of remaining Mondays given a day, month, year of your choosing.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# Monday = 0
def get_remaining_mondays(year, month, day):
    count = 0
    try:
        d = datetime(year, month, day)
        wday = d.weekday()

        d += timedelta(days=7 - wday)
        while d.month == month:
            count += 1
            d += timedelta(days=7)
    except ValueError as v:
        return v

    return count


print(get_remaining_mondays(2017, 11, 7))
```